# Javascript - keeping variable in scope after function has been declared

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, closures

I have some javascript code that takes a function and invokes it again:

```
var obj = {
  // returns the function with prevent default prepended.
  run: function(functor, context){

    return function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      context.call(functor, e);
    };
  }
}

var myContext = this;
var returnedFunction = obj.run(function(e){alert(e.target)}, myContext);
var returnedFunction(...);
```

Here is the problem:

On the line where it says `context.call(functor, e);`

`context` is always null because the function has gone out of scope.

What do I have to do inside that function so that I can use `context`?

Comment: Then declare `context` as a larger scope in `obj`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: And if you need different functions to use different `context` values? What the OP's doing makes perfect sense, there's just a minor error in it...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes you are right. The function `call` itself on `context` is not defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`context` has not gone out of scope -- it's probably just `null` to begin with (and even if it weren't, it likely wouldn't have a `call` method).

Instead, you probably meant to use `functor.call(context, e)`.

Functions have a `call` method, which accepts a `this`/context argument and variable-length following arguments. Objects in JavaScript generally *don't* have a `call` method that accepts a function and variable-length following arguments (unless you've added such a method and expect `context` to have it).

Comment: I suspect that `context` *isn't* `null`, but that the OP was misunderstanding the error "undefined is not a function" (caused by `context.call` being `undefined`). Nice catch, btw, I didn't get there until I was creating a live example demonstrating why the code worked -- and then it didn't. :-)

Comment: You are correct. I had it backwards. I'm a bumdass.

Comment: @user3621156: Easy mistake to make, easy mistake to read past.